# Creating \newcommand - I made a mistake

Tags: beamer, frame

I am using the document class beamer and writing my presentation.

I wrote

```
{\hskip-0em\vskip-0em\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}TITLE-TEXT}
```

To get some titels in the same style as the subtitle.
Everything works fine to that point.
To simplify I tried to create a function that looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\hskip-0em\vskip-0em\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}#1}
```

To apply it I simply write:

```
\mytitle{TITLE-TEXT}
```

The problem is that the following text has the same styling as my title.
With the fist approach this is not the case.

What is wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first version is in a group so the settings end at the `}` but the definition is not making a group (the `{...}` just delimit the definition, change it to `{{....}}` so that it adds the group as before.  (the `-0em` h and v spaces look rather strange but that's unrelated)

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Comment: @GCMeccariello if you had provided a test file I'd have posted an updated example, but `\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{{...}}`  with an extra `{}` so it adds the same group as you used without the definition.